# Compute connection matrix

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The (pseudo)Riemannian metric and the connection in $R^3$ with coordinates $x=u_1$,$y=u_2$,$z=u_3$ are given on the basic vector fields by

$$(\partial_{u_i}, \partial_{u_j})=\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial{u_1}\partial{u_i}\partial{u_j}}$$
$$(\nabla_{\partial_{u_i}}\partial_{u_j}, \partial_{u_k})=\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial{u_i}\partial{u_j}\partial{u_k}}$$ 
where $f=0.5(x^2z+xy^2) +ay^2z^2+bz^5$

How to compute connection matrix?
I need find relations between the  constants $a, b$ because of which  the connection is flat.

Comment: Partial derivatives should not have the variables as subscripts. This makes your formulas impossible to read, as well. You have a formula for the Christoffel symbols; have you written out all the mess? Please post your work and ask a specific question where you get stuck.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I need to get a metric firstly, right? If I get, the other computations are clear. But how to get it I don't know.

Comment: The first equations give the metric. What does $(,)$ mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin: It is a scalar product.

Comment: What is a metric?